# Blazor Webassembly server2 project reference added to server1 project, Server2 controller methods not calling

Tags: blazor-webassembly, hosted

I created a webassembly hosted project with two hosts (server projects), I added server2 project as a reference to server1 project, But when I want to call a method from server2 from client it is not called!

I also added api2  `[Route("api2/[controller]")]` as the path for server2 project's Controllers and call it like:  `var result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync($"api2/account/getkeyiv");`.

What is the solution to this that I can call server2 controllers methods from client?